# Loop through array and remove data in table based on array value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create a drop list for our database. I'm having to loop through the tables in order of dependencies and remove the data from the bottom up.

My sql so far:

```
DECLARE @CorporationId AS uniqueidentifier  = '60657416-CF5B-4F1B-91C1-8917E0AC95C5'

DECLARE @MyList TABLE (Value NVARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Common.Address')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Company.Tax')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Company.Batch')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Synchronization.Error')

DECLARE @COUNTER INT = 0;
DECLARE @MAX INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @MyList)

WHILE @COUNTER < @MAX
BEGIN

PRINT 'REMOVING ALL @CorporationId FROM @MyList'
DELETE FROM @MyList WHERE CorporationId = @CorporationId

SET @COUNTER = @COUNTER + 1

END
```

I'm getting this error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 18 Invalid column name
> 'CorporationId'.
>
> Completion time: 2021-07-06T12:25:59.6763246-05:00

The column does exist so I'm not sure why it's giving me an issue.

Comment: The column does NOT exist. Your statement that sets up @MyList (`DECLARE @MyList TABLE (Value NVARCHAR(50))`) only has the one column (`Value`) in it.

Comment: @RobJarvis: I guess that should be an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't parameterize an object name.  So use dynamic SQL, and a cursor instead of that strange loop.  eg

```
DECLARE @CorporationId AS uniqueidentifier  = '60657416-CF5B-4F1B-91C1-8917E0AC95C5'

DECLARE @MyList TABLE (Value NVARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Common.Address')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Company.Tax')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Company.Batch')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Synchronization.Error')

declare @tn sysname;
declare c cursor local for select Value from @MyList;
open c;
fetch next from c into @tn;
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
  declare @sql nvarchar(max) = concat('DELETE FROM ', @tn, ' WHERE CorporationId = @CorporationId');
  print @sql;
  exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@CorporationId uniqueidentifier', @CorporationId=@CorporationId;
  fetch next from c into @tn;
end
close c;
deallocate c;
```

Comment: Careful, @ErocM, this code is dangerous; it is open to injection. If you *are* injecting object names **always** use `QUOTENAME`.

Comment: As the object names appear as literals in the code and are inserted into a table variable, there's no vector for SQL injection in this case.

Comment: There's always a sql injection troll, even when this is clearly a DB cleanup script that doesn't have any app input. This is the kind of case where if someone could change the values in the table variable, they wouldn't need sql injection because they could just wreak the havoc they want directly.

Comment: But honestly, what is the point of the dynamic SQL at all? Why not just write 4 DELETE statements and save yourself all the hassle?

Comment: @AnthonyHancock SQL injection is not just about *security*, it's also about *correctness*

Comment: I am not trolling @AnthonyHancock , it's **2021**, SQL injection should be dead... It's not. People keep on making the same mistakes that their predecessors did... Learn from other people's mistakes. I *don't* appreciate you calling me a troll. With respect, I would suggest that calling me that means you don't understand how big a problem, and a plague on DBAs, it continues to be.

Answer (score 0):

I feel it is needed that I elaborate on my comment to David's answer:

> Careful, @ErocM, this code is dangerous; it is open to injection. If you *are* injecting object names **always** use `QUOTENAME`.

What I am saying here is that there is no evidence that the values being inserted into `@MyList` are being sanitised, and the values are being blindly injected. This means that someone could insert the value `N'Common.Address; DROP TABLE Common.Address;--'` into the table and the table, `Common.Address` would be dropped!

For the design you have, you'll need to use `PARSENAME` to properly split the 2 part name into schema and table names, and then `QUOTENAME` to properly delimit identify the object:

```sql
DECLARE @CorporationId AS uniqueidentifier  = '60657416-CF5B-4F1B-91C1-8917E0AC95C5'

DECLARE @MyList TABLE (Value NVARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Common.Address')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Company.Tax')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Company.Batch')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Synchronization.Error')

DECLARE @SchemaTable nvarchar(257); --128 * 2 + 1
DECLARE TableCursor CURSOR LOCAL
FOR
    SELECT Value
    FROM @MyList;

OPEN TableCursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @SchemaTable;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX) = N'DELETE FROM ' + QUOTENAME(PARSENAME(@SchemaTable,2)) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(PARSENAME(@SchemaTable,1)) + N' WHERE CorporationId = @CorporationId;';
    --PRINT @SQL; --Your best friend
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql, N'@CorporationId uniqueidentifier', @CorporationId=@CorporationId;
    FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @SchemaTable;
END;

CLOSE TableCursor;
DEALLOCATE TableCursor;
```

Ideally, however, I would define your variable `@Mylist` as the following:

```sql
DECLARE @MyList TABLE (SchemaName sysname,
                       TableName sysname);
```

Then you would instead define 2 variables and just use `QUOTENAME` on those; there would be no need for the `PARSENAME`.

Comment: SQL injection is not just about *security*, it's also about *correctness*. The code needs to work in all situations, therefore it needs to parse the object names correctly. Honestly I don;t know why this is a cursor anyway

Comment: @Charlieface , I agree that I could have gotten rid of the `CURSOR`, however, my main focus here was improving David's answers in respect to the injection.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't actually need a cursor at all, you can just aggregate one big query, and as mentioned by @Larnu, it needs `QUOTENAME` to prevent errors:

```sql
DECLARE @CorporationId AS uniqueidentifier  = '60657416-CF5B-4F1B-91C1-8917E0AC95C5'

DECLARE @MyList TABLE (SchemaName sysname, TableName sysname);
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Common','Address')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Company','Tax')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Company','Batch')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('Synchronization','Error')

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = (
    SELECT STRING_AGG(CAST(CONCAT(
'DELETE FROM ', QUOTENAME(SchemaName), '.', QUOTENAME(TableName), ';') AS nvarchar(max)), '
')
    FROM @MyList l
);

PRINT @sql;  -- for testing

EXEC sp_executesql @sql,
  N'@CorporationId uniqueidentifier',
  @CorporationId = @CorporationId;
```